# Is notifyItemInserted expensive

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm moving my application from sqlite to Firebase. Previously I would read N items from the DB to an arraylist and call `notifyItemRangeInserted`. Now the most convenient way to get data from Firebase delivers objects one by one. I was wondering if anyone benched the cost of calling `notifyItemInserted` for each list item. Is that fine or should I batch my loads? I'm displaying everything in a RecyclerView.

Comment: Good question. Is there anything that keeps you from running a test comparing the two? I'd love to hear the result.

Comment: The answer here will be highly dependent on your data architecture, payload, frequency--almost every detail of your specific use case. What do you see if you profile the two?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation for RecyclerView:

> There are two different classes of data change events, **item changes** and **structural changes**. **Item changes** are when a single item has its data updated but **no positional changes** have occurred. **Structural changes** are **when items are inserted, removed or moved** within the data set.

`notifyItemInserted` : Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at position has been newly inserted

`notifyItemRangeInserted` : Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected itemCount items starting at positionStart have been newly inserted

Its a bit tricky to quantify and compare these two.

1. **Based on the functionality:** Both of them seems to perform same operation. They don't alter the existing items binding but rather alter existing items position.
2. **Based on impact after notify observer:** Calling `notifyItemInserted` in short interval would trigger the registered observers frequently. If those observers are doing some heavy computation then `notifyItemInserted` for each item would be expensive.

However, if you do have list that is not sequential in a range (e.g. remove item 1, 2 and 4), or if you want to perform insertion and removal simultaneously, and have it animated accordingly or you frequently modifying the adapter's dataset, efficient way would be to implement `DiffUtil` which is available in support library.

> Most of the time our list changes completely and we set new list to
>   RecyclerView Adapter. And we call notifyDataSetChanged to update
>   adapter. NotifyDataSetChanged is costly. DiffUtil class solves that
>   problem now. It does its job perfectly

You can find more information [here](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00).